# Yii2 - To add Additional Button in Action Column

Tags: button, yii2

I am beginner for Yii2. 
By default, the framework provides View|Update|Delete buttons in the list view. The following code displays above action buttons.

```
[
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
...
...             
],
```

Now I want to add one more button (*i.e. Book Now*) in this ActionColumn. I also tried with 'button' but I get error. May be I didn't use properly.

So I will be thankful to you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

This is an example how you can to add buttons:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'context' => $this->context,
    'buttons' => [
        'edit' => function ($model, $key, $index, $instance) {
            $urlConfig = [];
            foreach ($model->primaryKey() as $pk) {
                $urlConfig[$pk] = $model->$pk;
                $urlConfig['type'] = $model->type;
            }

            $url = Url::toRoute(array_merge(['modify'], $urlConfig));
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>',
                $url, [
                    'title' => \Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ]);
        },
        'remove' => function ($model, $key, $index, $instance) {
            $urlConfig = [];
            foreach ($model->primaryKey() as $pk) {
                $urlConfig[$pk] = $model->$pk;
                $urlConfig['type'] = $model->type;
            }
            $url = Url::toRoute(array_merge(['delete'], $urlConfig));
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>',
                $url, [
                    'title' => \Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                    'data-confirm' =>
                        \Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure to delete this item?'),
                    'data-method' => 'post',
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                ]);
        }
    ],
    'template' => '{edit}{remove}'
],
```

Comment: I found alternative approach for it :

 [
       'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
       'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {clients-visa/create} {clients-visa/}',
       'buttons' => [
        'clients/create' => function ($url) {
         return Html::a(
           '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"> </span>',
           $url,
           [
           'title' => 'Add Client',
           'data-pjax' => '0',
           ]
         );
        },

        ...,
       ],
         ]

Comment: You may post this solution as an answer, we'll vote it up